# Convert string enclosed list to list

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert a list enclosed in a quotes to a list. Is their any optimal way to do this.

```
Ex: list = "[1,2,3,4,5]"

Operation : Convert list which is string to a list

o/p: list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: PS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd, personally, use JSON for this as it would be the appropriate library for storing and retrieving lists and dictionaries:

```
import json
li = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
li = json.loads(li)
print(li)
```

Alternatively, you could use `eval`, but it's not recommended:

```
li = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
li = eval(li)
print(li)
```

Comment: don't encourage to use eval

Comment: @Hackaholic I disagree.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: What... I said it wasn't recommend Ed in the post.

Comment: i am saying the string can be manipulate, when passed to eval, it will execute.

Comment: Fair enough I'll update in the morning

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to *safely* evaluate the string:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

```
In [1]: from ast import literal_eval

In [2]: literal_eval("[1,2,3,4,5]")
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

eval is evil use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3,4,5]")
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`lst=eval("[1,2,3,4,5]")`

Answer (score 0):

Most direct:

```
li = eval("[1,2,3,4,5]")
```

`list` is a reserved keyword, don't use it as a variable name.

Only use `eval` if your string comes from a trusted source; if you call `eval` on a string like `"import subprocess;subprocess.run('rm -rf /')"`, you're going to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

for me most simple way is:
`l=eval("[1,2,3]")`

Comment: It's also the most dangerous way.